# FloatThead and ExcelLikeBootstrap - Rendering issue

Tags: javascript

I'm using 2 javascript plugins : floatThead and Excel-like-Bootstrap-Table-Sorting-Filtering-Plugin

The sticky header is working great until you try to filter the rows. You can only see the div inside the table header when the page is at the top. Once the header is moving, the filter button doesn't display anything

I made an example in JS Fiddle (full code also below - just duplicates the rows to have a certain amount) :

https://jsfiddle.net/9713qa6n/

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Excel-like-Bootstrap-Table-Sorting-Filtering-Plugin/excel-bootstrap-table-filter-style.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="" />
    
    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Excel-like-Bootstrap-Table-Sorting-Filtering-Plugin/excel-bootstrap-table-filter-bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/floatthead/2.2.4/jquery.floatThead.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
<!-- Table to be filtered with a sticky header -->
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-intel sticky-header">
        <!-- Header that should remain sticky and having filters -->
        <thead>
          <tr class="table-info">
            <th>Animal</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Collective Noun</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <!-- Body of the table that should be filtered -->
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Bear</td>
            <td>Mammal</td>
            <td>Sleuth</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ant</td>
            <td>Insect</td>
            <td>Army</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Salamander</td>
            <td>Amphibian</td>
            <td>Congress</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Owl</td>
            <td>Bird</td>
            <td>Parliament</td>
          </tr>
          ........
        </tbody>
      </table>
      
      
      <script type="text/javascript">
            // Use the plugin once the DOM has been loaded.
            $(function () {
              // Apply the plugin 
              $('#table').excelTableFilter();
              $('.sticky-header').floatThead({
                        position: 'absolute'
                    });
            });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to get this fixed. Any help would be very welcomed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Misha Koryak

> This is not this filter's fault, they cannot be expected to handle what other plugins do to the DOM.
> Here is an ugly hack that solves your problem:
> https://jsfiddle.net/08hf4pdt/
> It also voids the warranty on the flaotthead plugin, but I doubt you care :)

```
    $(function () {
      // Apply the plugin 
      $('#table').excelTableFilter();
      $('.sticky-header').floatThead({
                position: 'absolute'
            }).closest('.floatThead-wrapper').find('.floatThead-container').css('overflowX', 'visible');
    });
```